# IP camera Streaming using java servlet and html over internet

Tags: java, video-streaming

I want to access IP Camera video stream(MJPEG) in servlet and send the response stream to html page so that i can use html5 video tag to display this live stream. 
I have written the code in doGet() where i have taken the camera stream in buffer using HttpURLConnection and sent it on ServletOutputStream. 
I have also set the response type as response.setHeader("Content-Type", "video/x-motion-jpeg") because camera returning mjpeg stream.But its showing nothing in html page.

Please suggest whether i am going correct or not.I don't want to use applet tag to display live video.